# How to do a search in a local api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to perform a search in a local API, but I still do not have the necessary knowledge, below is what I have implemented so far. My goal is for components to be rendered when the user types, well, I have a second problem, the  component is being redrawn into a single column.

edi1 -> when I type in the input I get the following error:
 '`TypeError:'? q = $ "is not a function` '

**File App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchString: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ searchString: data.results }) 
  }

  onChange(fieldName){
    /*
    fetch(data.results.title+'?q=$(field)')
    .then(console.log(field)) 
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({ searchString : json }))*/
    fetch(this.state.searchString.title+'?q=$'(fieldName)).then(response => response.json()).then(json =>
    this.setState({ searchString : json }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
        <div className="container mt-10">
          <div className="row">
            <RecipeItem list={this.state.searchString} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**File Navbar.js**

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {

    handleChange = e => {
        const fieldName = e.target.value;
        console.log(fieldName);
        this.props.onChange(fieldName);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div className="navbar-brand col-1">
                    <img src={logo} className="Navbar-logo" alt="logo" />
                </div>  

                <div className="form-group justify-content-center row col-10 my-2">
                    <input
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                        className="form-control col-9 mr-2"
                        type="search"
                        placeholder="Search"
                        aria-label="Search"
                    />
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you've stated your goal but not your problem. what's not working?

Comment: when I type in the input I get the following error 'TypeError:'? q = $ "is not a function '

Comment: try adding + sign before fiedName like    +'?q=$'+fieldName

Comment: Are you trying to set the fieldname variable with the dollar sign? if so then it looks like what you have commented out is the correct syntax except you want curly braces inside of backticks instead of parentheses like so: '?q=${fieldname}' or you could just use the plus sign after with single quotes '?q=' + fieldname

Comment: add
'? q = $' + fieldName
made me advance, but now it returns the following error
'Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token <in JSON at position 0.'

Comment: What data point are you trying to hit.  Is it a backend api or just a dataset?  You usually get this type of error when you are returning html instead of json.  This can happen when your route is not found and your returning the html 404 page but its hard to tell without seeing your setup.  If you are trying to hit an api do you get json when you type it into your address bar?

Comment: to a folder inside my directory in src / sample_data / recipes.json is where I am collecting the data, after that I pass the data to a variable and assign it to the created state.

Comment: fetch uses http so unless you can access it with an http request then fetch isn't going to do much good that is why your getting the error because if its in your react src file then you can never access it through url.  You can just import it and parse through it from there.  Like `import json from 'the folder/recipes.json'`.  Also if you are just trying to acces a json file I don't know what good the '?q=${fieldname}' is going to do without a backend or some kind of javascript to serve up your query.